# Pandas / Numpy Won't Play Nice

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, numpy-ufunc

I am attempting to install Pandas and Numpy together so that they will work. I am currently getting the error "numpy.ufunction has the wrong size, try recompiling". Which seems to indicate that the version of Numpy that Pandas needs is incorrect. But I have tried numpy versions 1.5.0 for 32 bit, numpy 1.6.1 for 32 bit, numpy 1.7.0 for 32 bit, and numpy 1.7.1 for 32 bit windows.

I have to download the .exe and load it this way because if I try pip install numpy I get a cleanup error. So I can not figure out how to get Pandas and Numpy to work together. I would install Anaconda but also need win32com for scripts I use and am afraid of breaking something there.

I have uninstalled and re-installed the modules several times.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I am running Windows 7 64 bit and have ActivePython 2.7.6.9 MSC v.1500 32 bit loaded on the computer.

Thank you in advance. I have read several other postings but I still have not been able to work out my issue.

Robert

Comment: Maybe try one of the packaged "scientific python" distributions - Anaconda, Canopy?

Comment: "numpy versions 1.5.0" This is **very** old, pandas requires 1.7+ IIRC. Yes use anaconda. http://continuum.io/downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. You should get the 64bit version, try to install it from this site :

for Numpy http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy and download the **numpy‑1.9.2+mkl‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl** file

for Pandas http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas
**pandas‑0.16.0‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl** file

Comment: I went to the sites recommended above and was able to load in the win32 module that worked. - Thank you very much.